# Move layer only on a specific axis

Tags: krita

How would I move a layer on a specific axis? I would like to move a triangle on the *y* axis, so it will be properly centered.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for *Constrained movement* with the *Move Tool*.

From [the manual](https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/tools/move.html):

> If you click, then press the Shift key, then move the layer, movement
> is constrained to the horizontal and vertical directions. If you press
> the Shift key, then click, then move, all layers will be moved, with
> the movement constrained to the horizontal and vertical directions.

Comment: This works, thank you!